# 他のうちの人に、来たことを知らせます。社長室に入ります。何と言いますか。

Tags: honorifics

> 社長室に入ります。何と言いますか。
>
> 1. 失礼します。
> 2. ごめん下さい。
> 3. うかがいます。

According to my book, the correct answer is 1- 失礼します.

Yet, in another part of my book it states this:

他のうちの人に、来たことを知らせます。
at the time when you arrive at someone's home to let them know you’re there.

> Answer: ごめんください。
> Response: はい、どちら様ですか。/ どなたですか。

So the question is why is 1 correct and 2- ごめん下さい not correct in the original question above? Is it because you know your boss?

Answer (score 3):

It's because the 社長室 is not the president's **home**. For whatever reason, ごめんください is used only when you're in front of someone's **home**. Basically it's polite "Hello!".